# Flutter-web Autoroute, issue trying to directly access to nested route

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an app with 2 screens:

- List of Merchants: screen show a list of merchants
- Single Merchant: screen with Tabs, each tab should show some widget and should have its own route

The routes are configured like this:

```
AutoRoute(
  path: '/merchants',
  name: 'MerchantsRoute',
  page: EmptyRouterPage,
  guards: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    AutoRoute(path: '', page: MerchantsView, guards: [AuthGuard], initial: true),
    AutoRoute(
      path: ':id',
      page: SingleMerchantView,
      guards: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        AutoRoute(path: 'dashboard', page: Dashboard, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantDashboardRoute'),
        AutoRoute(path: 'purchases', page: PurchasesList, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantPurchasesRoute'),
        AutoRoute(path: 'profile', page: PurchasesList, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantProfileRoute'),
      ]
    ),

  ]
),
```

**SinglMerchantView** is the widget containing the **AutoTabsScaffold** and the **TabBarView**

Using **flutter web**, when I access directly (by typing directly the url in chrome) to:

- **/merchants** ==> It works
- **/merchants/some_merchant_id** ==> It works, showing correctly the SingleMerchantView with first tab selected and the **Dashboard** built
- **/merchants/some_merchant_id/dashboard** ==> It doesn't work like expected. I'm expecting that the **SingleMerchantView** is first created, then it should create the **Dashboard** widget
  What I see is that it's trying to create directly the widget **Dashboard** without creating the widget **SingleMerchantView**. As Dashboard widget is expecting a mandatory **id** property (which is normally injected by the parent **SingleMerchantView**) then the page fails

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need an EmptyRouterPage for each of the nestles. Something similar to this:

```
AutoRoute(
  path: '/merchants',
  name: 'MerchantsRoute',
  page: EmptyRouterPage,
  guards: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    AutoRoute(path: '', page: MerchantsView, guards: [AuthGuard], initial: true),
    AutoRoute(
      name: 'SingleMerchantRouter',
      path: ':id',
      page: EmptyRouterPage,
      guards: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        AutoRoute(path: '', page: SingleMerchantView, guards: [AuthGuard]),
        AutoRoute(path: 'dashboard', page: Dashboard, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantDashboardRoute'),
        AutoRoute(path: 'purchases', page: PurchasesList, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantPurchasesRoute'),
        AutoRoute(path: 'profile', page: PurchasesList, guards: [AuthGuard], name: 'MerchantProfileRoute'),
      ]
    ),

  ]
),
```

I haven't been able to test, but it is similar to an issue I had today.

Comment: Doing this, even navigating normally  (from Merchants page -> SingleMerchantView page) doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I use to get the same issue with auto_route.
It seems to be a bug with the package...

[Flutter-Web : How to access a page from the URL with auto_route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72664030/18262850)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).